# Custom Keyboard Input

Tags: c#, input, keyboard, handle

How can I read custom keyboard input on c# ? (prefer wpf)

My keyboard has extra buttons (like main , volume up-down,mute). How can I read when some of them are pressed ?

Also if it is possible I want to be able to read them without my app to have focus. E.g even if my app is minimized or another program has the focus (eg. explorer.exe)

Comment: 1) Simply obesrve the params in a keypress/keydown event! 2) You may want to look up on 'global keyboard hooks'

Comment: @Taw thanks for correcting my question. Will this work https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook when pressing custom keyboard buttons ? ( cant test right now , I haven't vs on this machine)
EDIT: Just builded it with msbuild and it seems that work ! (even for my custom keyboard buttons but not all of them). Thanks for your help !

Comment: I don't know, but it should. Those keycodes probably are nothing too weird.. (Btw: Did you re-insert the c# in the title? It really shouldn't be there, as it is already in the tag..)

Comment: Ohh i will remove it now. Anyway because of you I searched for "global keyboard hooks" and I found the above repository (I was searching for "c# custom keyboard input" and I was getting weird results). Thanks !!

Answer (score -1):

Check this : [GlobalMouseKeyHook](https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook)